# iOS - Views inside other views

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

As I have told you many times, I'm new to iOS development.

I've learned something about views, view controllers, views hierarchy and stuff like that, and I'm thinking about one thing.

Assume that I want to create some app using some tab section, some table section, drawing canvas with context menu (`quartz2D`) etc, and I would like to have all these things visible at a time (static application) and can ensure some interaction between all these sections (changing something in the canvas results in some changes in the table, editing some values via context menu on canvas results in drawing a charts in tab pane and so on...).

The question is, if it is efficient to put all views on one screen and have some viewcontroller inside viewcontroller inside viewcontroller inside v...

How should I manage all particular views (with controllers) assuming that I have to present all of them at a time during entire application workflow?

```
/* PS. I'm new to StackOver as well, so let me know if such basic and not concrete questions like that one, are unwelcome */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 UIView *v1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 270, 400)];
    v1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIView *innerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 240, 370)];
    innerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [v1 addSubview:innerView];

    [self.view addSubview:v1];

    for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
    {
        //You can get all subView object that You added
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't add `ViewController` inside a `ViewController` , you have one view Controller and on it's `View` you add `SubViews` Buttons, labels,...etc.

You can iterate on the `subViews` by get `self.view.subViews` 
If you have a complex view, please make it as `CustomView` that inherits from `UIView` to make the code readable and well organized.

Comment: Thanks, you mentioned the CustomView